# Detecting the platform(OS) on which browser is running in gwt

Tags: gwt, cross-platform

I want to detect whether my site (browser actually) is running on Windows or Linux. I want to do this because I am copying some data to clipboard from my site and this data contain multiple lines. I want to know whether I should append `\n` (linux) or `\r\n` (windows).

In Java we can do this using `System.getProperty("line.separator");`. **But I am using gwt.**
How to do this in gwt?? (I think there should be a way to detect platform in gwt, but I didn't find one on googling).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this:

```
Window.Navigator.getPlatform();
```